# Create a new data frame column that indicates the period (month) from a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing a column of dates indicating when a forum post was made ['post_month], ranging from November 2017 to January 2023. From these I want to create a new 'period' column, that indicates the period that the post was made. So posts made in Novemeber 2017 would be period (or month) = 1, December 2017 period (or month) = 2, January 2018, period (or month) = 3 and so on... up until the final period of January 2023.

What would be the most suitable way to do this?

My data looks like this:

| age | binary_target | post_month | cohort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 0 | 2018-04-01 | 2019 |
| 34 | 0 | 2019-02-01 | 2019 |
| 44 | 1 | 2018-09-01 | 2017 |
| 27 | 0 | 2018-03-01 | 2022 |

Answer (score 1):

You can convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), subtract your reference and get the number of periods:

```
df['period'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['post_month'])
                  .dt.to_period('M')
                  .sub(pd.Period('2017-10', freq='M'))
                  .apply(lambda x: x.n)
               )
```

*NB. since you want to count from **1**, we make the reference October 2017.*

Alternative vectorial solution:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['post_month'])
ref = pd.Timestamp('2017-10-01')
df['period'] = date.dt.year.sub(ref.year).mul(12).add(date.dt.month.sub(ref.month))
```

Output:

```
   age  binary_target  post_month  cohort  period
0   63              0  2018-04-01    2019       6
1   34              0  2019-02-01    2019      16
2   44              1  2018-09-01    2017      11
3   27              0  2018-03-01    2022       5
```